# problem with Display error messages in angular js

Tags: javascript, angular6

I need to display error message, when service issue.

i use below function to load data to the dropdown. function is loading in page load.

```
 component
loadOrgNames(){
      this.orgNameModel = this.dataserviceService.getOrgName();
     }
```

service

```
  getOrgName() : Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.orgnameurl);

  }
```

how i handle errors in my service class.

Answer (score 0):

the function getOrgName return an Observable, if the value is correct for dropdown use async pipe on your html. or use it like below:

```
this.dataserviceService.getOrgName().pipe(
tap(data => {
this.orgNameModel = data;
```

}))

Answer (score 0):

This is how a service that returns Observable should be consumed.
Error should be handled like below:

```
loadOrgNames(){
    this.dataserviceService.getOrgName().subscribe( response => {
      this.orgNameModel = reponse;
    },
    errorResponse => {
    });
}
```